# Catch nested interface value

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the values of a json that was obtained by means of a request.

But I'm not getting the value `foo1`, I've tried everything but I can not get the value.

The `invalid operation` error appears.

Can you help me?

```
{
    "result": {
        "foo1": 1751,
        "foo2": "2018-12-17T00:00:00-02:00",
    }
}

url := "mysite"
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

defer res.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

byt := []byte(string(body))

var dat map[string]interface{}

if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(dat) //map[result:map[foo1:1751 foo2:2018-12-17T00:00:00-02:00]]
fmt.Println(dat["result"]) //map[foo1:1751 foo2:2018-12-17T00:00:00-02:00]]
foo1  := dat["result"]["foo1"] //invalid operation: dat["result"]["foo1"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
fmt.Println(foo1)
```

Comment: You need to type assert it first https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @zerkms's comment, you need to type assert it to `map[string]interface{}`.
[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/W0hezUg7gul)

P.S: Performing a nil check before assigning is always a good idea.

`if exists := dat["result"]; exists != nil {
    foo1 := dat["result"].(map[string]interface{})
}`